# Is there any reason to use Win32 API (in C or C++) over .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi, api

I'm finishing my summer job where I write graphical software for our baggage scanners. Everything is done in .NET or MFC, with plain C++ for hardware communication (I don't do any of the hardware stuff). I sometimes resorted to Win32 API calls such as SendMessage to improve performance of a form or control. I've had only a year's worth of CS courses (all in C), but I am fascinated by the Win32 API--it is much larger and more powerful than I thought.

Does .NET simply hide all of the "tedious" or ground level work of the Win32 API? Does the final software consume more system resources or perform slower in .NET?

Comment: I agree. I love the Windows API. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580381/the-coolest-parts-of-windows-api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.Net generally makes development eaiser.  It does this by providing a system which makes the common activities take less effort from the developer.

I love working in .NET.  Before it became available, I worked primarily on a GUI written in C++ using MFC and Win32.  When I switched to .NET, I had to totally revise my estimates because I could get stuff done faster!

To answer your actual questions:  There are less-common development scenarios where .NET does not help (and some might say it gets in the way).  Those generally involve low-level use of hardware communication or finely-tuned COM programming.

Note that you can do develop in C++ for .NET, allowing you to cross between Win32 and .NET with little to no effort.  (It isn't standard C++ when you develop to the CLR, but it isn't tough to pick up the differences, either.)

Don't consider performance without an actual scenario that you can actually test.  For an interesting performance comparison of .NET and C++ on the same task, check out the blog entry (and links!) here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/05/10/416151.aspx

**UPDATE**
The link above is old. Here is one that works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-sixth-cut

Answer (score 10):

> Does .NET simply hide all of the "tedious" or ground level work of the Win32 API? Does the final software consume more system resources or perform slower in .NET?

Yes, it *tries* to hide all the tedious details. And yes, a .NET application *will* generally be slower and is likely to consume more resources than a similar application written in C and Win32.

But the sacrifice in performance is usually a negligible price to pay for the gains in productivity and ease of maintainability.

I understand that the l33t-ness factor of programming so close to the bare metal using simple C and pure win32 might look very tempting, but I find it hard to justify when it would be many times easier and faster to use .NET.

Comment: Unless you're performance tuning all of your C++ code, the statement "a .NET application will generally be slower" is highly misleading. During the first run of the app, or during the first load of any .NET app after a reboot, you might see this. But afterwards, C++ and .NET are on equal ground -- it's the skill of the developer which determines whether the app is fast or not. (And .NET can make it easier for less-skilled people to develop quicker apps.)

Comment: I don't know, John. I don't have any performance benchmarks to support my claim, instead I'm making what seems to me to be a reasonable assumption: That the ease of use and well-designed abstractions that .NET offers will be paid for by some performance loss. I'm the first to admit that this hypothetical degradation in performance is negligible or near non-existent 99% of the time, but that it is still there. I think we are basically agreeing on principle, but splitting hairs on the details :)

Comment: Maybe.  Check the link in my answer to see if that changes your view at all.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer to your questions, are "no", "yes", and "not necessarily", in that order. That is to say, .NET does much more than "hide" the Win32 API, it wraps it in some cases, expands upon it in others, and completely ignores it in still other cases.

Software developed with the .NET framework will often consume more resources than the lean-and-mean hand-coded assembly that could (theoretically) be produced by an expert, but in many cases, the C or C++ developer will use frameworks and toolkits that are just as heavy as the .NET framework, and the difference will be a wash. The other thing to consider is that it usually doesn't matter if a program consumes a few extra kb of memory these days. Noone notices. If the benefits of developing in .NET (or any other technology) outweigh the risks, then it's a better choice. Only you can tell that for your particular situation.

As for "performance", that's an awful big category, but since .NET code is compiled to machine language (it's not interpreted), generally there is little difference. Again, the hard-code assembly programmer will likely beat it, but apply your cost-benefit analysis to determine if it's worth it to you.

Answer (score 5):

The appeal of .NET is that it is a *more productive* development platform. Many parts of the .NET framework do provide a partial wrapper of Win32 API's. Although the framework does, indeed, abstract away a lot of "tedious" Win32 API calls, that doesn't stop me from needing a little PInvoke every now and then.

You will find that the .NET framework does involve a little overhead and is not strictly as efficient as C or C++ is capable of being; however, often the tradeoff is between productivity and efficiency. The requirements of the individual application will determine which is more important. In a lot of software, the requirements are to be "efficient enough", and may be entirely suited to .NET development.

Comment: Watch out for generic performance statements.  Basic, first-attempt, code in .NET could be faster than similar C++ code that has even had some performance tuning done to it.  (Check out the link in my answer for some specifics.)

Comment: @John: Point well taken. That was why I chose the verbiage "not strictly as efficient as C or C++ is capable of being". I considered that adequately non-universal in its application.

Comment: It may be helpful to review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138361/how-much-faster-is-c-than-c, which contains a discussion about the general performance comparison between C and C#. As @John observed, measurable performance differences are not universal, but I find that, in practice, they frequently do exist.

Answer (score 3):

All that you mentioned is "layered" on top of Win32, yes. Win32 is one of the lowest levels you can programmatically work in with Windows. In my opinion, it is tremendously beneficial to learn Win32.

Pretty much everything is based on it. (That and COM.) It's just like learning how registers work on a CPU, instead of it being a black-box.

All the really good (professional) Windows programmers I know, know it and know it well.

[**Programming Windows**](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) by Charles Petzold is pretty much the bible for Win32 and IMO, is well-written and executed.

Btw, I think anyone who is an “engineer in their heart” as much as in their head always needs to know how things work. I think it’s a Good Thing.

Comment: For clarity, I'm NOT saying don't learn .Net. Do so if you like. I'm only commenting on learning Win32.

Comment: Of course not. I did a little .NET in high school with VB and now I'm doing a LOT in C# for work. It's great and extremely productive, but I am interested in learning Win32 API on my own and writing a few simple programs. When I am comfortable enough with Win32, I would like to write a tiny IRC client that does the bare necessities of what I need (I dislike using add-ons for other clients).

Answer (score 3):

.NET is *intended* to hide the tedious details of the Win32 API. It succeeds at that in some respects, but fails in others. If most of what you write fits well with what MS tries to support, it can succeed quite well. If you depart into "virgin territory", you can lose the advantage entirely, and even cause a great deal of extra work compared to native code using Win32 directly.

The resulting software (essentially always) consumes more resources than native code. The only real question is how *much more* memory it uses, *how much* slower it runs, etc.

These, unfortunately, are hard to answer. Speed can be anywhere from *essentially* identical to 8x slower or so. Memory usage is consistently quite a bit higher (e.g., at least 2x, often 3-5x. One interesting point is that garbage collection gives a trade-off between speed and memory consumption (running the GC more often reduces memory usage at the expense of using more CPU time). As such, execution time will depend as much on memory availability as CPU speed.

Interestingly, one of the first things I personally did with .NET was porting a C++ program that I *knew* had a memory leak (I even knew were it was and roughly how to fix it, but actually doing so would have been a lot of work). Porting to .NET didn't take very long (it wasn't a lot of code). The good news was the the memory leak was gone. The bad news was that as closely as I could figure, the leaky C++ code would have had to run continuously for over a year to use as much memory as the .NET version required just to start up.

Comment: The last paragraph is very similar to my experience with .NET. I wrote a program to view and search log files and it uses quite a lot of memory. A coworker wrote a very similar program in C++ years ago and it uses a fraction of the memory. My program would get up to 200MB when working with a 60MB text file and his would get up to 70-80MB if you load the entire file into the edit control.

Answer (score 2):

.NET let's you get started faster if you're learning, especially for building your form with a visual interface. That's very appealing for a while, but in my experience you end up finding some limitations.

Cons:

1-Requires the corresponding .NET framework version to be present on the client machine, which is not always guaranteed.

2-Problems with 3D graphics applications, discontinued support for .net directX. (SlimX engine works around this i think but still you're kind of stuck).

3-your 3D application may not run on newer versions of Windows without rework, or possibly no workaround, see #2. (I found this the hard way)

I've been studying Win32 for some time now and while it is more difficult to get started it does feel more powerful and leaner.

Cons:

1-You have to deal header files in your project, which takes some time for beginners to understand. There is a very specific way to work with these since the compiler is 'one-pass' and the order of things is important.

2-The win32 API is more criptic, with everything in a more or less common namespace, the big list is cumbersome to explore.

3-There is no hint/description on the members' autocomplete display, so you have to spend weeks pouring over all the different members' documentation.

4-There are no automatic 'callbacks' like in .NET (i.e. On_button_click), you have to process the Windows elements via 'messages' handled by the 'wndproc' functions. This takes some time to get your head around, especially if you come from .NET. And again you have to pour through a ton of documentation to figure out what message names and parameters you need.
This paradigm in itself is not a problem, but it makes it difficult to separate your actual application from your Windows gui design.

5-Again since Windows elements communicate via 'messages' you don't get sensible or descriptive autocomplete options as with actual member functions'
See this pseudo code:

> button.text="abc"; //in this case you understand the possible options

vs

> SendMessage(button_hwnd, BN_SETTEXT, "abc", 0); //need to see     MSDN/StackOverflow

6-No automatic de-allocation of object memory. But i think this is not too bad. 
The c++ classes have a ~name() destructor function where you can deallocate things when the instance is destroyed.
I also try to use dynamic arrays for members that instantiate at run time, this helps in actually being orderly and takes care of the actual allocation procedures.
pseudocode:

> class game{
>
> std::vector(ghost) ghosts;
>
> }
>
> update{
>
> ghosts.pushback();  //add one, etc
>
> ghosts.erase(position); //any element can be killed off. this is pretty good
>
> }
>
> ~game(){  //
>
> ~ghosts();          //deallocates array
>
> }

So what i've seen so far is you just have to be a bit more mindful and structured to prevent memory leaks, but otherwise i wouldn't let manual deallocation be a concern.

Regarding portabilty, I would argue if the application is well encapsulated it shouldn't be too hard to port to other platforms. Not worth it to depend on the .NET framework, which ironically defeats portability itself. 
But everyone's mileage varies of course.

But regardless of the cons, so far I'm happy with Win32, I've invested about 2 months learning and I've built my own wrappers for the Windows controls, so it's easier to build up and interact with the windows form programmatically.

I also run the irllicht 3D engine on the form, and it seems to run flawlessly on several machines with different versions of Windows. It's great to see the executable run on any (Windows) machine without dependencies or installations.

Programs load faster and seem smaller in size. However performance-wise, i think there is no big advantage these days AFAIK.

I believe Microsoft should've just written some simple wrappers for the API, together with some nice example and template projects, instead of going with the whole bulky .NET route.

Just my $0.02

**Edit:** I understand MFC wraps some of the functionality, but i've read it adds some overhead, and it hasn't really caught on. Hope someone could add on this as i haven't really played with it.
Oh here [[Is it worth to learn Microsoft Foundation Classes(MFC) Nowadays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943456/is-it-worth-to-learn-microsoft-foundation-classesmfc-nowadays][1])

Comment: *"MFC [...] hasn't really caught on."* - MFC was released in 1992, and ships with every release of Visual Studio (except the Express Editions). It has received support for almost 25 years. *"I believe Microsoft should've just written some simple wrappers for the API"* - They did, in the form of MFC, or Windows Forms/.NET's BCL, or even the Windows Runtime, if you want something lightweight.

Comment: Please stop the arguments here. If you wish to continue this discussion, I recommend taking it to chat.

Answer (score 0):

I base my answer on one thing: C++ is an iso standard. C# is a proprietry Microsoft language.

If you ever want to extend your skills past Windows, iso C & C++ will see you much further.

.NET has a has a large framework - but if you know where to look there is a HUGE body of lgpl and (if youre compatible with it) gpl open source software written for C & C++. boost is becoming a massive library that has most of the (non GUI) functionality offered by .NET, but in a cross platform standard.

That said, if you don't mind selling your soul and comitting your career to the ongoing success of a single Company... C# / .NET has two big bonuses that the Win32 API doesn't offer:

- Its hard to write c++ code that does not leak. For all that I hate the idea of garbage collection, it is effective.
- WPF is where Microsoft have put the pretty things for UI development since XP. they look just like the normal windows controls: buttons, text boxes, listviews, that native Win32 apps get, but under the cover they support flicker free painting, are alpha aware, and can be animated and skinned.

Comment: PS. Im sure Microsoft is at least as stable as a company founded in 1850, that dealt in 100's of billions of dollars in credit daily.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehman_Brothers
Wait. They went bankrupt.

Comment: Had to downvote, for being so poorly researched, and full of false information. C# was officially published as ISO/IEC 23270:2006 standard in 2006. It can be used outside of Microsoft Windows (e.g. in the [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)) project, started in 2004). Today, you can write C# code to target Windows, Android, and iOS. As for flicker-free painting: That's a feature of the Desktop Window Manager as well, first available in Windows Vista (released 2006/7). Native windows have been double-buffered by default ever since. Incidentally, WPF was introduced with Vista.

Comment: And of course, today [the majority of the .NET framework is open-source](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/).