# Passing a pointer-to-class-member as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to write a function that apply a process to member of a class. The following code is working:

```
class AA
{
public:
    AA(){};
    ~AA(){};
    std::string type="AA";
};

class BB
{
public:
    BB(){};
    ~BB(){};
    template <typename T, typename TT>
    void test(T& a, TT(T::*memberPtr))
    {
        std::cout<<"test: "<<(a.*memberPtr)<<std::endl;
    }
    std::string type="BB";
};

int main()
{
    AA a;
    BB b;
    b.test(a, &AA::type);
}
```

But I know everything at compile-time so I am wondering if it is possible to write something equivalent but only with templates? So I could write something like:

```
b.test<&AA::type>(a);
```

that calls inside test(a):

```
std::cout<<"test: "<< (a.*MEMBER) <<std::endl; // MEMBER is given in template
```

or something like that.

Comment: You could pass a pointer to a getter method instead of the member variable.

Comment: The `memberPtr` variable in your `test` function already does what you want - member function pointers are runtime values.

Comment: I realize that I may have misunderstood what my pointer memberPtr really is... is it determined at compile time or at run time? Is there any cost for using (a.*MEMBER) compare to just writting 'a.type' ?

Comment: @user52730 I expect there to be the cost of dereferencing a pointer but that's probably insignificant and this is premature optimization. Unless you have measured your code and confirmed this is particularly problem I would focus on making things clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do just `test<&AA::type>`, since you'd need to also tell the function template what *type* of pointer-to-member you're expecting. The typical pattern is:

```
template <class M, M member, class T> // deduced go last
void test(T& a) {
    cout << (a.*member);
}
```

With usage:

```
test<decltype(&AA::type), &AA::type>
```

I believe there's currently a proposal to reduce the verbosity there, but until then, it's not the worst thing in the world, and you could always:

```
#define TYPE_AND_VAL(foo) decltype(foo), foo
test<TYPE_AND_VAL(&AA::type)>
```

---

That proposal I mentioned is in C++17, and will allow you to do:

```
template <auto member, class T>
void test(T& a) {
    cout << (a.*member);
}

test<&AA::type>(a);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is closer to what I want but I am wondering: you still use pointer so I guess it is determined at runtime? (I am not really aware of function pointers) As I exactly know which member I will point to at compile time, I guessed it was possible to define everything at compile time.

Comment: @user52730 This *is* at compile-time. Template arguments must be known at compile time.

Comment: Ok and can you confirm that my code was dealing with the pointer at runtime? Function pointers are still quite obscur to me.

Comment: @user52730 Yes, you're passing an argument - that's a good sign that it's at runtime. There are no function pointers anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to SergeyA's answer but a compromise would be to pass your class and a lambda. The compiler is able [to inline the lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722515/3422652) so you will probably not pay for it at run-time:

```
struct BB
{
public:
    template <typename T, typename F>
    void test(T& a, F f)
    {
        std::cout<<"test: "<< f(a) <<std::endl;
    }
    std::string type="BB";
};

int main()
{
    AA a;
    BB b;
    b.test(a, [](AA& a){return a.type;});
}
```

You may (or may not) find this clearer than using pointer-to-class-member.

Comment: That's interesting thanks! I look for something more readable than lambda though.

Comment: @user52730 Personally, I find lambda's more readable than pointer-to-member-function syntax but ok. You can use `auto` with lambdas if you want to give it a name.

Answer (score 0):

Just eliminate this somewhat strongly typed altogether. Instead of requesting user to provide you with a class and the member poiner, just accept templated functor and call it's operator(). This will be most flexible and least verbose.

Comment: It does not answer the question but you are probably right, I will explore this possibility, thank you!