# Can you specify class a member as template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to figure out if you can do this with templates:

```
template <typename T, (something here)>
void DoSomething(T& class_object)
{
    std::cout << class_object.(something here) << std::endl;
}
```

In other words, can you pass a member object you would like to access to the template somehow?  I can't seem to find any examples anywhere.  I know that you could do it with a macro:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING(T, member)
void DoSomething(T& class_object)
{
    std::cout << class_object.member << std::endl;
}
```

But I'd like to use templates if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T, auto T::*m>
void DoSomething(T& class_object)
{
    std::cout << (class_object.*m) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rTn471srK)

Comment: So the precondition for this is that `m` has to be a public member of struct/class right?

Comment: Doesn't have to be public. The code that instantiates `DoSomething` needs to be able to access it; `DoSomething` itself doesn't need any special access. E.g. a method of a class could call it, passing the pointer to a private member. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KGz7qaTcc)

Comment: So - I just realized I am stuck on C++ 14 for now - is there a way to do this without the auto specifier?

Comment: Ahhh - found it for C++14:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119056/passing-a-pointer-to-class-member-as-a-template-parameter