# How to handle std::find_if() returning false?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, stdvector

Take the following example taken from [the cplusplus.com reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/?kw=find_if) and altered to return `false`:

```
// find_if example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::find_if
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool IsOdd (int i) {
  return ((i%2)==1);
}

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;    
  myvector.push_back(10);
  myvector.push_back(20);
  myvector.push_back(40);
  myvector.push_back(50);

  std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
  std::cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Since no value in `myvector` is odd it will return *InputIterator last*, which is undefined:

```
The first odd value is -1727673935
```

What is the proper way to handle this output?

How can I know `std::find_if()` returned `false` if the output is unpredictable and comparing to the entire vector to confirm the resulting value doesn't exist defeats the purpose of using `std::find_if()` to begin with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);

if ( it != myvector.end() )
{
    std::cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << '\n';
}
else
{
    // std::cout << "there is no odd value in the vector\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic way to do this is to check whether the iterator equals the end sentinel.

```cpp
auto it = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
if (it == myvector.end()) {
    std::cout << "No odd values found" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

In C++17 (the most recent standard), you can declare the iterator right in the `if` statement:

```cpp
if (auto it = std::find_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd); it != myvector.end()) {
    std::cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "No odd values found" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**[std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)** returns(*reference [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)*)

> Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or **last if no**
>   **such element is found**.

That means, dereference the iterator only when its **not equal to container.end()** iterator.

```
if (const auto iter = std::find_if(myvector.cbegin(), myvector.cend(), IsOdd); // need C++17 compiler support
    iter != myvector.cend())
{
    std::cout << *iter << "\n";
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

---

**PS**: In modern C++, lambdas expressions should be your good friends, and use it when it is appropriate.
See more here: [Why can lambdas be better optimized by the compiler than plain functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722426/why-can-lambdas-be-better-optimized-by-the-compiler-than-plain-functions)

That means your `IsOdd` could have been

```
constexpr auto isOdd = [](const int i) /* noexcept */ { return i & 1; };
```

Comment: The verbosity of a lambda is not useful or needed here

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Admit the fact. Usually, there will be a nitpicking *unrelated* comment on this kind of questions, that "hey why don't you use lambdas instead of a free-function?"; There is no one like that. Hence thought to provide the OP an extra tip/ info
along with the answer, in-case he/ she is not aware of that. Sorry if it is too verbose and misleading.

Comment: Just an observation on your remark "use it whenever it's possible", which seems like an overly strong recommendation. "Use it when it's appropriate" would be better, if a little self-evident.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if the returned iterator is the end iterator you passed to `std::find_if` (the second argument). These semantics are quite common for algorithms in the standard library, so you should get used to this.

```
const auto firstOdd = std::find_if (myvector.cbegin(), myvector.cend(), IsOdd);

if (firstOdd != myvector.cend())
    std::cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "No odd values found\n";
```

Note also that you can use the `cbegin()`/`cend()` member functions, as you're not mutating the container.

Comment: "*compares equal to **the one-past-the-end iterator** of the container you're searching through*" - it is more accurate to say that it should be "the end iterator that you pass to find_if()" instead, which in this particular case *happens* to be the one-past-the-end iterator of the container, but that is not always the case when working with iterators in general.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the hint, that makes sense indeed. I improved the wording.