# What is the most efficient way to check if a string matches one of the possible inputs?

Tags: c++, coding-efficiency

I'm asked to accept both a number and a unit, where a unit can be cm, m, in or ft.

For this I have a loop as such

```
cout << "Please put in a number and its unit.\n";
while (cin >> val >> unit) {
    if (val == '|') { break; }
    cout << "Please put in a number and its unit.\n";
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to check the unit string, when it comes to code efficiency as well as readability? Does it make more sense to put a large if statement

```
    if (unit != "cm" && unit != "m" && unit != "in" && unit != "ft") {
        cout << "Unit " << unit << " not accepted.\n";
    }
```

Or is it better to have a vector which I initialise with all the units, and then check if it matches any of the units.

```
    if (find(units.begin(), units.end(), unit) == units.end()) {
        cout << "Unit " << unit << " not accepted.\n";
    }
```

... where `vector<string> units = {"cm", "m", "in", "ft"};`

Or is there another way which is much better in terms of efficiency and readability?

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. I thought about code review but it doesn't seem to fit a small question like this.. or does it?

Comment: Entirely a matter of taste.  "Efficiency" is irrelevant since you are waiting for user input and running this just once each time enter is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Your "if" statement is not only more efficient, but efficiency doesn't matter because no matter how you do it, the IO will take about a billion times longer.

It's also the most maintainable because if you format the "if" statement as one line per unit string, then adding, removing, or renaming a unit is only a 1-line edit, and you can easily comment them out or in if you change your mind.

The time to use a vector is if you don't know what the units are until run time.

Comment: Allocating memory for the vector would also take longer than the `if` statement.

Comment: I quite like the idea of hoisting the possibilities off into an array and using `std::find` on that. That's way more maintainable than a long chain of conditions in an `if` statement

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, that's a matter of taste. :) If you need the list in more than one place in the code, then I agree.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Yep fair

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I used to use macros for this. Then somebody decided those were "evil".

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Funnily enough I just did a similar thing with macros this morning :P Sue me!

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make more sense to put a large if statement?

The only four entries, I would say that you do not need to use `std::vector`(and the allocation cost comes up with it) and an algorithm to test the case. If the length of the if the condition is bothering you, pack the condition to a lambda function and call with the user input.

Proper naming of lambda would give much readability than checking the variable directly inside the `if` statement.

```
const auto isMatchingUnit = [](const std::string& unit) noexcept -> bool {
    return unit == "cm" || unit == "m" || unit == "in" || unit == "ft";
};

if (isMatchingUnit(unit)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

---

That being said, if the number of *possible input* s are large, you might wanna pack the possible inputs to `std::array`or `std::vector` and apply the standard algorithms as per choice:

If the collection to be checked **is sorted and unique** you can

- [std::binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) which returns `true`, if item is found.
- [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) by checking `std::lower_bound(container.cbegin(), container.cend(), input) != container.cend()`, for `true` case.

If the collection to be checked is **not sorted**

- [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) by checking `std::find(container.cbegin(), container.cend(), input) != container.cend()`, for `true` case.
- [std::any_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with a proper predicate.

Comment: What "allocation cost" with `std::array`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant about `std::vector`. will edit!

Comment: Why a lambda? Good case for a normal function, this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hope you know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722426/why-can-lambdas-be-better-optimized-by-the-compiler-than-plain-functions)

Comment: There are no function pointers or anything of that kind here. Don't see the relevance

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What if the function(here lambda) needs to be called once. Do you prefer the definition next to where it's been called or somewhere else in the translation unit? especially for a function which has a single return statement as a body.

Comment: If it's a utility that only makes any semantic sense within the lexical scope of that function, a lambda. If it's a more general piece of logic, as it appears to be here, I'd prefer a proper function elsewhere in the TU where it's easy to spot & maintain (even if currently only used once). But that's definitely subjective :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195643/discussion-between-jejo-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient would be using [std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) on a *sorted* array of strings, so it doesn't search all of them. If you use direct comparison or std::find, then all will be searched.

For a small vector, it might not be important (it might even be slower than a direct comparison), but for larger sets it will.

Comment: For four entries I doubt the difference is measurable.

Comment: Yes, but later on when he has more entries there will be one.

Comment: The problem statement says "where a unit can be cm, m, in or ft" and I doubt it's going to have to deal with thousands of different units any time.

Comment: Agree with @Jonathan Also in the general case where the num of entries is (very) large and the entries themselves are (very) large, building a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be needed for efficiency

Comment: In that case he shouldn't be asking anyway, a direct `if ==` is better.