# How to call std::for_each on a vector of std::function without lambda?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to callback functions, that are stored in a vector, e.g.,

```cpp
std::vector<std::function<void()> xs{};
std::for_each(xs.begin(), xs.end(), [](auto& func) { func(); });
```

But how do I make the code work without using a lambda? I tried the following, but it doesn't compile:

```cpp
std::vector<std::function<void()> xs{};
std::for_each(xs.begin(), xs.end(), &std::function<void()>::operator());
```

Error: `In template: called object type 'void (std::function<void ()>::*)() const' is not a function or function pointer`

Comment: What is the problem with using a lambda?

Comment: @Jodocus I don't like C++ lambdas. They are too verbose. I prefer function pointers if possible.

Comment: @Sheldon: Your "preference" is a *bad* preference. See [Why can lambdas be better optimized by the compiler than plain functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13722426/364696)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) takes *"UnaryFunction"*.

Instead, you might use [`std::ranges::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/for_each) (C++20) which takes "invocable".

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> xs{};
std::ranges::for_each(xs, &std::function<void()>::operator());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3xq6hcqWs)

Answer (score 0):

Define a function.   That's all a lambda w/o captures is - a function with no name.

```
void Callback (std::function<void()> &func) { func(); }

std::vector<std::function<void()> xs{};
std::for_each(xs.begin(), xs.end(), Callback);
```

Comment: A lambda without captures is still a unique type (equivalent to a stateless funct*or*), not a funct*ion*. It matters for optimization; templates specialize on the type, and `Callback` here is a type that encompasses *any* function returning `void` and receiving `std::function<void()> &`. The lambda would be a unique type the template could specialize to completely. See [Why can lambdas be better optimized by the compiler than plain functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13722426/364696)

Comment: I want to avoid any type of function, that simply forwards the call